# How to use cache response for Retrofit with OkHttp when network response returns error

Tags: android, caching, retrofit, okhttp

I have a simple use case: Use network response when success. Else use cached response.
But the problem is that when network response is an error, the cache is also written with that response.

One of the suggestions I read is to do FORCE_CACHE in the Interceptor when networkResponse is not successful.
But since the networkResponse overrides cache with error, next time when you request (and the server still returns an error), the cache will have an error.

Below is my current snippet. I need to add logic for returning cached value when networkResponse is an error. Any suggestion will be greatly helpful.

```
private void setup() {
    OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    builder.addInterceptor(REWRITE_CACHE_CONTROL);

    File httpCacheDirectory = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "responses");
    Cache cache = new Cache(httpCacheDirectory, 10 * 1024 * 1024); // 10 MB
    builder.cache(cache);
}


private static final Interceptor REWRITE_CACHE_CONTROL = new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    public okhttp3.Response intercept(@NonNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        if (!hasAConnection()) {
            request = request.newBuilder().cacheControl(CacheControl.FORCE_CACHE).build();
        }
        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
};
```